# insert column to table which shares a key with another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, merge

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct function to do what I'd like to.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
insert into assets(owner)
(select a.Username as whatIwant
from dbo.DIRECTORY a join dbo.ASSETS b
on a.Ext = b.Ext)
```

I have one table with assets (dbo.assets) which has a column (ext) with the number of the phone extension that asset is tied to.  In the other table (dbo.directory) I have a column with the number of the phone extension (ext) tied to the name of the person that resides at that extension (username).

What I'd like to do is insert the username of the person tied to the phone extension into dbo.assets under a new column: owner.  So, the ext has to match up with the username.  Should I be using merge instead?

Comment: 1) Add new column to table 1st then commit changes 2) change your insert into an update as the record already exists in assets, you simply want to update the record setting the username column to the username column from dbo.directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which RDMS your are using.  Either way you need to add the column to the table first then you would update the row setting the column value.  In SQL Server it would look like this.

```
ALTER TABLE assets ADD owner VARCHAR(20) NULL



update a 
set a.owner = b.username
from assets a
inner join directory b on a.ext=b.ext
```

Comment: Apologies, yes I'm using SQL Server 08.  This query worked great, thank you